# tkinter after() lagging after period of time

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I was writing code to show time every second and then noticed that eventually after some time(approx 30 seconds) time starts lagging behind the original time. I was able to reproduce the issue, so was someone I know. Hopefully you guys too can reproduce this.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

win = Tk()
win.geometry('400x400')
frame=Frame(win)
frame.grid()
labelTD=Label(frame)
labelTD.grid(row=2,column=0)

def countdown(n):
    mn, secs =divmod(n, 60)
    hr, mn = divmod(mn, 60)
    labelCD.config(text=f"{hr:02}:{mn:02}:{secs:02}")
    labelCD.config(font='infra 50 bold',foreground='black',background='white')
    labelCD.grid(row=0)
    if n >= 0:
        labelCD.after(1000, countdown, n-1)
    else:
        labelCD.destroy()

def clock():
    t=time.strftime('%A''\n''%D''\n''%I:%M:%S',time.localtime())
    if t!='':
        labelTD.config(text=t,font='infra 50 bold',foreground='black',background='white')
        Hr = time.strftime('%H')
        Mn = time.strftime('%M')
        Sc = time.strftime('%S')
        if int(Hr)==8 and int(Mn)==41 and int(Sc)==0: ### you can trigger it at any time you want
            countdown(3600)
        labelTD.after(1000,clock)

labelCD = Label(frame)
labelCD.grid()
clock()

win.mainloop()
```

Could this be due to usage of `after()` or calling the function every second for a long time? If so, any alternatives to show timers? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Running your code for more than a minute. I just experience a delay less than a second. Is this the issue?

Comment: @Atlas435 Yea, the delay of a second, itll grow larger with in increase in time

Comment: It runs now more than 5 minutes and it just seems unsynchron. For this I would set the after to 200ms. But Im still not sure if I experience the issue you are talking about.

Comment: @Atlas435 The unsynchron. with the original time is what im talking about.

Comment: The gap will be bigger and then it will meet a closer point it synchronize the time. Even if you find a way to start the timer at the same point the second changes on the clock, it still will get out of the synch, since the after method just promises to not call the function earlier. Like I said you can call after 200 ms and the gap will be closer but still not synchron.

Comment: @Atlas435 Any other libraries exist? That does this better? with tkinter? I searched and couldnt find any.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225562/discussion-between-atlas435-and-cool-cloud).

Comment: Try moving the `after()` line to the beginning of `countdown()`.

Comment: @acw1668 It reduces the lag, well maybe the lag is permanent, and will be there. I think there is no way to get id of it. After all python is slow xp

Comment: Did you do the same on `clock()`?

Comment: @acw1668 Yep, still lagging behind.

Comment: @CoolCloud [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166283/13629335)

Comment: @Atlas435 Sure got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `after` method doesn't guarantee any sort of precision. The only guarantee it makes is that the function will be called some time *after* the requested timeout. It could be at 1000 ms, it could be at 1001, 1010, or something else. It depends on what else is going on in the system.

If you need something more accurate, you can save the current time in ms in your function, and do some math from the previous time your function ran, and then use that delta to adjust your calculations.

Comment: Could you give some example of such calculation?

Comment: @CoolCloud you would do something like `delay = ms-(this_time-last_time)` and `.after(delay, func)`

Comment: @Atlas435 Maybe add an answer?

Comment: @CoolCloud dont be lazy :D I need to work something else out.